# Jenkins Git Plugin Could Not create .ssh folder

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, 64-bit, msys

I'm getting this error in my Jenkins server

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@mygitrepository.com:my_username/myrepository.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Could not create directory '/home/my_username/.ssh'. 
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/my_username/.ssh/known_hosts). 
Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't know why but the plugin tries to create .ssh under /home/my_username/, which doesn't exist in Windows. I'm trying to route it into another folder "say C:/Jenkins" but setting USERPROFILE or HOME envr. variable doesn't do the job.

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your job is running on the "windows slave" you expect it to run?  Are you mixing this with "cygwin"(which has /home/<user> concept).  Check the user account in which the windows slave is running. (please add more info by editing your question).

Comment: Hi @Jayan, sorry for the delayed response. 

I'm not sure what you mean by running on the windows slave. I just had Jenkins logged in as an Administrator from Services under Administrator Tools and going with it. 

Cygwin is installed in my pc, yes, but how exactly can I be "mixing" ? What do you mean by that?  And please, ask me what you want to know :)
Thanks

Comment: Could you remove cygwin from machine and try?  I had difficult time with "cygwin" git/ssh not working with jenkins plugins

Comment: I did , unfortunately it didn't work. And before that I tried echo $HOME at cygwin terminal it echoed /users/my_username , not /home/my_username. 
Maybe that's not it ?

Comment: For debugging, create another job that just prints information such as hostname, user account, home directory account.  Then run it on the target slave.  My working version has no cygwin in it.